# Methods for Linear system solution with matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, numerical, spline

I have a linear system Ax = b , which is created by natural splines and looks like this:

[image]

where     [image]

The code in matlab which is supposed to solve the system is the following:

```
 clear; 
 clc;

x = [...] ;
a = [...];
x0 = ...;
n = length(x) - 1 ; 

for i = 0 : (n-1) 
    h(i+1) = x(i+2) - x(i+1) ; 
end


b= zeros( n+1 , 1 ) ;
for i =2: n 
    b(i,1) = 3 *(a(i+1)-a(i))/h(i) - 3/h(i-1)*(a(i) - a(i-1) ) ;
end


%linear system solution. 

l(1) =0 ; m(1) = 0 ; z(1) = 0 ;

for i =1:(n-1) 
    l(i+1) = 2*( x(i+2) - x(i) ) - h(i)* m(i) ;
    m(i+1) = h(i+1)/l(i+1);
    z(i+1) = ( b(i+1) - h(i)*z(i) ) / l ( i+1) ;
end

l(n+1) =1;
z(n+1) = 0 ;
c(n+1) = 0 ;

for j = ( n-1) : (-1) : 0 
    c(j+1) = z(j+1) - m(j+1)*c(j+2) ;
end
```

but I can't understand which method is being used for solving the linear system.
If I had to guess I would say that the LU method is used, adjusted for tridiagonal matrices, but I still can't find the connection with the code...

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: To solve the linear system `A*x = b`, you would usually simply use `x = A\b`. To build the matrix `A`, look up the `diag` command. You could compare `x` and your solution `c`, if it's even correct.

Comment: It uses a triangular matrix solver. See page 115 of the numerical recipes book (http://nrbook.com/c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients look a little odd (particularly that `2` in the `l` equation), but it looks like a specialized [Thomas Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm) where:

1. The second-to-last loop performs a forward elimination of the subdiagonal to bring the matrix into upper triangular form.
2. The last loop performs the back substitution for the solution.

The code doesn't seem to match one-to-one with the general algorithm since the solution is using the vectors that compose the diagonals instead of the diagonals themselves with no apparent preallocation of memory.  So I can't say if this method is "better" than the general one off the bat.